# (WPF) (TextBox) turn off prediction candidate

Tags: wpf, textbox

I want to turn off prediction candidate function in WPF TextBox
[image]

It occurs when inputting Japanese as in the image above.

I know how to turn that feature off in windows.

But I want to turn that feature off via WPF source.

Comment: Do you work in UWP?

Comment: MSDN says that `TextBox.IsTextPredictionEnabled` _"property doesn't affect Input Method Editor (IME) for Japanese or Chinese languages. __Text prediction for these languages is shown even if this property is false__."_

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.